# Sourcetree - How to take an old commit and force it to top?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Doing a proto with people that barely know the technicalities of sourcetree (myself included).
I pushed a huge update at marked CL "A", then gave it an update at B. Someone somewhere after this nuked the entire thing, I think with a faulty merge.

How do I take the files from that commit and force them over the top level? (My update was huge, the following are worth stomping over if necessary). I don't understand all these functions of Rebase and Patches and such.

[sourcetree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUyNK.png)

Comment: I'm on a bit of a time crunch, so I'm sure there's a better solution, but I set my local to that CL, exported all objects and dependencies related to my CL, forced to head and reimported :P